# Why UITableview scrolling up while reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` with 40 to 50 sections. It is expandable tableview when ever tapped on Section header am expanding that corresponding section if already expanded it will close. My issue is when ever I tapped on Section header requesting server for data and received data from server my Tableview automatically scrolled to top and this is happend after 20th section only. I could not understand whats going wrong.

```
NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.section];
[self.tableview reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: What kind of cell are you using for your data? If you use a variable height cell this will occur. Is the expected behaviour that after the data is loaded that the tapped section header be at the top of the table?

Comment: am using Defalut  UITableviewCell and cell height and section height both are dynamic , its scrolled to Top (section 0)

Answer (score 1):

If you do something which changes the height of some of the cells the table will scroll to a different position after the reload.
If you want the tableview to scroll to the top of the tapped section once the load has finished, what about something like:

```
 NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section];
 [self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 NSIndexPath     *sectionPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:section];
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:sectionPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: If it is scrolling to the the top of the table though, are you doing something to the dataSource which is setting the number of sections in the table to zero, and then resetting it immediately afterwards?